# Python Mechanize fill textarea and submit a get-method form

Tags: python, html, forms, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to get the METAR code converted on the web first then scrape the results.

But now I am facing a problem where the form's method is `GET`.

This is my first time to use mechanize to do this.
I don't know how to enter the text into the textarea and get the result.

Below is what I have tried:

```
#Metar decoder scraper
import mechanize;
br = mechanize.Browser();
br.set_handle_robots(False); 
metarUrl= 'http://www.metarreader.com/';
br.open(metarUrl);
br.select_form (nr = 0);
#A metar code sample here
br["convert"] = ["METAR UAAA 192000Z 16007MPS 9999 -SHRA BKN050CB OVC100 15/13 Q1009 882/0250 TEMPO TSRA"];
results = br.submit().read();
print results;
```

Comment: When you inspect the network requests in Chrome for example, you can see the conversion is done through an AJAX call: `http://www.metarreader.com/scripts/ajax.php?ajax=CONVERTMETAR&metar=METAR+UAAA+192000Z+16007MPS+9999+-SHRA+BKN050CB+OVC100+15%2F13+Q1009+882%2F0250+TEMPO+TSRA`. I would simple urlencode your METAR code ans build the AJAX query and fetch the result through `mechanize` or something else

Comment: You are very helpful! Thank you. Can you give me some tips on reading the network requests from the inspect element box. Sometimes I get confused while reading them. I do not know the function of different pages except for those gif, png...

Comment: Using Chrome: 1) go to http://www.metarreader.com/; 2) right-click > "Inspect Element"; 3) Choose "Network" tab (make sure "All" is highlighted at the bottom, or "XHR"; 4) enter code in "Convert METAR" textarea + click "CONVERT" button; 5) observe a GET request being sent and the reply, click on it, look for "Request URL"

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I mean is that is there any tip or reference on how to differentiate whether the file download for a webpage is useful or not

Comment: and by the way, I have already figured it out using your methods, thanks a lot

Comment: how do I mark the answer number of your suggestion. it seems that the question is still showing 0 answer

Comment: that's because I only added a comment. since I haven't proposed a complete answer with mechanize code, I did not post as an answer. You can however post your own answer if you figured it out with my hint, I don't mind :)

Comment: as for the tips on determinig which requests are useful or not, I guess it's experience, and probably size of response, really depends.